# How to reindex archived as well as non archived data using searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick, ruby-paranoia

I have a `Meeting` model which contains archived as well as non archived data.

When I am running `Model.reindex` only non archived data is getting indexed.

I want to index non archived data as well so that I can see non archived data as well when using `search` method of searchkick.

For archiving I have used `paranoia` gem and archived column name is `cancelled_at`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Model.with_deleted.reindex
```

Since paranoia gem default_scope is always without the deleted/archived ones just have to use the helper scope that is documented in the paranoia readme https://github.com/rubysherpas/paranoia#usage

Comment: Thanks. But in my search result i am not getting archived records. Getting [searchkick] WARNING: Records in search index do not exist in database: 59, 2. My search function:                                                                                        
def self._search params, fields = [:name] 
    search_text = params[:search].present? ? params[:search] : '*'
    per_page = params[:per_page] || 25
    return self.search search_text, fields: fields, match: :word_start, order: {updated_at: {order: 'desc', unmapped_type: 'long'}}, page: params[:page], per_page: per_page
end

Comment: I guess thats how searchkicks works. The search index returns an object that searchkick is looking up on `Model` but since its hidden searchkick errors out. You could overwrite the `default_scope` of `Model` then it should work again, but this leads to the issiue that your hidden objects are not hidden anymore. For this you have to plan a little bit ahead an think of a structure for it.